# Call a function after User delete Excel Work Sheet in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, excel-interop

I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` and I need to call a custom function when User delete a Excel Work Sheet (Right click on sheet name and delete).

How can I access the Work Sheet delete event?

I found `WorkbookEvents_SheetBeforeDeleteEventHandler` in Microsoft Docs, but I'm looking for something like `AfterDeleteEventHandler`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Just a suggestion which falls into hack category: start a timer on "before" event  and poll the worksheet for sheet existance for some acceptable time then drop the timer. If the sheet becomes really deleted you will have opportunity to detect it this way. This solution clearly a hack (hey anybody, please do not downvote because of this!) but if you do not found any other possibility this may work.

Comment: @cly Thanks for the suggestion. Btw, looking for a solid solution rather than a hack :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what [WorkbookEvents_Event.SheetTableUpdate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbookevents_event.sheettableupdate?view=excel-pia) does (description is not really descriptive...), maybe it will be raised after a sheet has been removed? Other candidates I would check are SheetActivate and SheetDeactivate.

Comment: @Steeeve Thanks for the suggestion. I think, I can do something with `SheetActivate`

Answer (score 1):

If a worksheet is deleted another sheet becomes an active one, so handling the [Workbook.SheetActivate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheetactivate) event can help. It is fired when any sheet is activated. In the event handler you may check whether a "deleted" sheet still exists or not.